# MongoDB: Only fetch documents created in the last 24hrs?

Tags: mongodb

I want to limit a query I'm making to only look in documents that were created in the past 24 hrs.

What is the best way to structure this query? How do I go about limiting based on date?

Comment: This link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665731/find-last-document-of-the-day-for-the-last-7-days

Comment: Start with [docs on native driver](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/). I personally use [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin). There's also [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) and [others](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/mongodb). And of course see [DB's docs](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Home) itself (on [queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying) and other stuff). There's also free [M101: MongoDB for Developers](https://education.10gen.com/courses/10gen/M101/2012_Fall/about)  from 10gen.

Comment: @elmigranto i use node-mongodb-native // i know how to use mongo i just don't know the best way to do this query.

Comment: Create `createdAt` field, create index on that, use `find({gte: isoDate})`. That's what I would do.

Answer (score 56):

Add `createdAt` field, index it,  then query

```
db.getCollection("COLLECTION_NAME").find({"createdAt":{$gt:new Date(Date.now() - 24*60*60 * 1000)}})
```

This will return all records younger than 86400 seconds.

Answer (score 21):

If you're not using any other indexes and are using the default ObjectID as your _id, you can do the following:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID

db.collection.find({
  _id: {
    $gt: ObjectID.createFromTime(Date.now() / 1000 - 24*60*60)
  }
}, callback)
```

Comment: JavaScript execution failed: ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined

Comment: TypeError: Object function ObjectId() { [native code] } has no method 'createFromTimestamp'

Comment: my bad, `createFromTime`. they might have changed it: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#objectid-createfromtime

Comment: Getting the same error: ReferenceError: ObjectID is not defined

Comment: Close, but I think it should be `ObjectID.createFromTime(Date.now() \ 1000 - 24 * 60 * 60)`.

Comment: Also, regarding the above comment about ObjectId not being defined – you need to import it from the MongoDB Node driver using `var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID`

Comment: is there any way to do the same code with spark?

Answer (score 13):

For anyone else landing here via google, you can do this in the mongo shell as follows:

```
db.collection.find({ $where: function () { return Date.now() - this._id.getTimestamp() < (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)  }  })
```

Comment: Be careful with `$where` http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#op._S_where It has performance issues.

Comment: TypeError: this._id.getTimestamp is not a function

Answer (score 6):

Use this in mongoose

```
let ObjectId    = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

Property.find({
    _id: {
        $gt: ObjectId.createFromTime(Date.now() / 1000 - 24 * 60 * 60)
    }
}, (err, result) => {
    console.log(err || result);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

first of all it would really help if you will provide people with a schema of your collection.

But just because it already 3 hours passed and no one replied I will try:

Suppose you have you entry and it has a field createdAt which is an ISODate:

```
{
somefield: "test",
createdAt: ISODate("2012-08-13T04:00:00Z")
}
```

So what you need to do is to put an index on this field

```
db.yourColl.ensureIndex({createdAt:1});
```

Then you get your current time in node.js substitute your 24 hours and get your value of start. (As far as I know there is no analog of NOW in mongdb. Right me someone if I am wrong.)

```
db.yourColl.find({
   createdAt: {
     $gte: start
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps someone. I'm using pymongo to query last 24 hours of data. In my case I had to convert the current time into BSON timestamp.

First I had to import Bson timestamp:

```
from bson.timestamp import Timestamp
```

Then in my search query I did the following:

```
yesterday  = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

findQuery = {
    "unix": {
        "$gte": Timestamp(int(yesterday.strftime("%s")),0)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting in `Mongo 5.0`, it's a nice use case for the new [`$dateDiff`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/#mongodb-expression-exp.-dateDiff) aggregation operator:

```
// { "_id" : ObjectId("60c8f804fb832fe2f2011657") }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { $expr:
    { $lt: [{ $dateDiff: { startDate: "$_id", endDate: "$$NOW", unit: "hour" } }, 24 ]}
  }}
])
// { "_id" : ObjectId("60c8f804fb832fe2f2011657") } // if document created within the last 24 hours
```

---

A few things to note:

- Basically, we're `$match`ing items for which the duration (`$dateDiff`) between their creation date (represented by their `_id`) and now (`$$NOW`) is less (`$lt`) than `24` `hours`.
- The start date is the `$_id` ([`ObjectId`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/bson-types/#objectid)):

  - Indeed, an `ObjectId` contains the timestamp of its creation
  - And `$dateDiff` can accept an `ObjectId` as a temporal representation
- The end date is [`$$NOW`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables), which is a variable that returns the current datetime value.

Answer (score 0):

"TIME" is field which store timestamp

```
db.your_collection_name.find({"TIME":{'$lt': new Date(),'$gte':new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))}},{}).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions are outdate new Date() etc. This will work in 2022 with updated golang:

Remember to include time module

```
import (
    "time")
```

Will use basic minute with - operator. Below it means 24 hours multiply with 60 minutes and .Add actually subtracts with minus operator:

```
"$gt": time.Now().Add(-60 * 24 * time.Minute),
```

İnclude filters:

```
filter := bson.M{
            "$and": []bson.M{
        {
            "createdat": bson.M{
                "$gt": time.Now().Add(-60 * 24 * time.Minute),
            },
        },
        {
            "userid": userid,
        },
        }}
```

Make sure defer cureser

```
cursor, _ := todoCollection.Find(ctx, filter, findOptions)

    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        var product models.ProductPost
        cursor.Decode(&product)
        products = append(products, product)
    }
    defer cursor.Close(ctx)
```

Get the length

```
fmt.Println(len(products))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await db.yourColl.find({
   "timestamp": {
       $lt: new Date(),
       $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-(24* 60 * 60 * 1000)))
   }
})
```

Works in my case

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and after a lot of searches, the best solution that I found for fetching data from last X days is something like this:

```
let date_obj = new Date();
let requestedTime = new Date(new Date().setDate(date_obj.getDate() - day));
    
    db.collection.find({
      createdAt: {$gt: requestedTime}
    });
```

the day variable must be a numeric value of the number of days you want, for example: 1 for one day ago (last 24 hours), 2 for two days ago (last 48 hours), 30 for the last month, 60 for the last two months, and so on. ..

```js
let date_obj = new Date();
let requestedTime = new Date(new Date().setDate(date_obj.getDate() - 1));

document.querySelector("#current_date").innerHTML = `current date: ${date_obj}`
document.querySelector("#last_24H_date").innerHTML = `last 24 hours: ${requestedTime}`
```

```html
<div id="current_date"></div>
<div id="last_24H_date"></div>
```

Comment: It's not safe to put date in client side as it can be manipulated

Comment: @Bitfinicon I didn't say to put date on client side. It's obviously should be on back end. I just wrote it like that so they can see it's output

Answer (score -1):

```
db.video.find({"timestamp":{$lt: new Date(),$gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()-1))}})
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not particularly helpful. Please add some descriptions of how this code solves the problem.

Comment: To expand on @shree's point, that's _especially_ true here, where there are **nine** other answers, some with quite a few upvotes, and most with explanations. If a new reader comes to this page and is trying to find a solution, what sets your approach apart from the existing answers? Under what conditions might your answer by preferred? Are you using new syntax that wasn't available when the question was first asked? That's the type of information that will make your answer a useful contribution to this thread.