# Query all documents createdate within last 24 hours, and group by hour?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

From reading various articles out there, I believe this should be possible, but I'm not sure where exactly to start.

This is what I'm trying to do:

I want to run a query, where it finds all documents createdate  within the last 24 hours, and groups all of them by hour, and since each hour document has a AVG "PM10" value and last 24 hours MAX_PM10 value,last 24 hours AVG_PM10_value.I want to run a query Iam getting each hour AVG_PM10 value remining  how to calculate each hour avg_PM10 value and total_PM10_avg value ,toatal_PM10_max value please any one suggest me

```
Here's a sample of the collection:

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ad768309ee4f03480792b20"),
        "CREATEDATE" : ISODate("2018-04-25T15:45:52.779Z"),
        "PM10" : 176.024749755859,
        "PM2DOT5" : 60.0020217895508,
    }
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ad768309ee4f03480792b30"),
        "CREATEDATE" : ISODate("2018-04-25T16:45:52.779Z"),
        "PM10" : 176.024749755859,
        "PM2DOT5" : 60.0020217895508,
    }

And the aggregation query:

    db.collection1.aggregate(
     {$match: {
       CREATEDATE: {$gt: new Date(new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24))}
     }},
     {$project: {  "h":{"$hour":"$CREATEDATE"}, "PM10":1 }},
     {$group:{ 
       "_id":"$h",
       "Max_PM10": {"$max":"$PM10"},
       "PM10": {$avg:"$PM10"} 
     }}
   ])
Expected output:

    {
        "Hour":15,
        "AVG_PM10_VALUE":154.64,

    }
   {
        "Hour":16,
        "AVG_PM10_VALUE":157.64,

    }


  "TOTAL_PM10_MAX_VALUE":157.89,
  "TOTAL_PM10_AVG_VALUE":156.14
```

Comment: So what is the problem? You're telling us what you want, and you're showing us what you have written, so now tell us what is wrong with it exactly

Comment: I want to run a query Iam getting only each hour PM10 value .remining  "LAST_24HOURS_PM10_MAX_VALUE":177.89,
"LAST_24HOURS_PM10_AVG_VALUE":144.67 was not found please suggest me

Comment: I've tried to explain to you before that we don't understand what you are asking because you are not actually asking anything. What does `""LAST_24HOURS_PM10_AVG_VALUE"` mean? What is "last 24 hours Average Value"? And how can that appear "grouped by hour"? Are you expecting it to be the same for every hour returned? We just don't know.

Comment: how to calculate each hour avg_PM10 value and all document avg_pm10 value and Max_pm10 value

Comment: @Neil Lunn   how to calculate each hour avg_PM10 value and  total_PM10_avg value ,toatal_PM10_max value

Comment: So you want the same number in every document in the output  then? i.e `{ "hour": 1, "max": 2. "last24avg": 4 }, { "hour": 2, "max": 6, "last24avg": 4 }` etc. So the "all results average" is `4` and it appears in every result.

Comment: Iam expecting out pur is{ "hour"1,"avg_pm10":154.23,"total_avg_pm10":120.87,"Total_max_pm10":186.8 }

Comment: @ Neil Lunn   { "hour": 1, "max": 2. "last24avg": 4 }, { "hour": 2, "max": 6, "last24avg": 4 } etc is write please suggest me

Comment: You cannot have a "total from all documents" as a value within "each document". Grouping just does not work like that. If you want it to appear that way in your final result, then run another query to get that "total average" and then alter each document obtained from this one to include that number. Can't be done in a single aggregation pipeline. Well not in any scalable way anyhow. Run two queries instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB: Only fetch documents created in the last 24hrs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314678/mongodb-only-fetch-documents-created-in-the-last-24hrs)