# Mongoose/Mongo: A query to find all documents older than five minutes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need mongoose to run a query that finds documents older than an amount of time described in milliseconds found in the config folder. This amount of time is stored like this,

```
keys.anAmountOfMilliseconds
```

Thus far, I've been able to pull all documents created in between NOW and FIVE minutes as described in this link. 
**[MongoDB: Only fetch documents created in the last 24hrs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13314678/mongodb-only-fetch-documents-created-in-the-last-24hrs)
**, but reverse engineering this query has so far been beyond me.

Any help would be amazing!!
Thanks!

Comment: "Older than" means "Less than" `$lt` and "Newer than" means "Greater than" `$gt`, optionally varying to `$lte` or `$gte` depending on what you mean. Not much to engineer here as "lesser" or "greater" is just *reversing* the expression used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you will want to use the less-than operator for building your query. To build off the answer you linked I think it will need to look something like this

```
db.getCollection("COLLECTION_NAME").find({"createdAt":{$lt:new Date(Date.now() - 5*60 * 1000)}})
```

Or for your case

```
db.getCollection("COLLECTION_NAME").find({"createdAt":{$lt:new Date(Date.now() - keys.anAmountOfMilliseconds)}})
```

Haven't had a chance to test but that should return all documents older than the amount of time you specify.